# JAVA: IO new File(filename) throwing "Can't read input file!"

Tags: java, io, base64

I'm trying to create a file from one server to another.
Server A executes script which needs to create a file one server B. Server A has a script that creates folder without issues (no permission denied or anything) and call the following code after creating the folder:

```
byte[] btDataFile = new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(base64);
File of = new File("driverLetter:\folder_path\filename.png");
FileOutputStream osf = new FileOutputStream(of);
osf.write(btDataFile);
osf.flush();
```

"base64" is a base64 string representation of a png image which I need to create as a file. The value of the string is quite long so I can't post it in here but it's there, not empty, not null, it has a value.
But the code throws the error:

```
"Can't read input file!"
```

Why can the script read the "input file"?
Thanks

Comment: The error is probably thrown by some other code you're not showing us. `"Can't read input file!"` doesn't sound like any standard Java error.

Comment: "\f" is a form character like "\n" and "\r".

Comment: nothing to do with the question, but instead of using sun.misc.BASE64Decoder, try the BASE 64 codecs in http://commons.apache.org/codec/ - the sun.misc packages are internal to sun and could change at any time.

Comment: And you shouldn't make up your own error messages. Use the one in the exception. Otherwise you suppress information about the actual problem.

Answer (score 5):

Use forward slashes in your file path. Or escape backslashes with `\\`.

Comment: It is recommended to use the property `File.separator`, instead of slashes.

Comment: IMHO, it's even more recommended to avoid hard-coding file paths in source code, and rather take tham as arguments or externalize them in config files

Comment: Using \\ doesn't solve the issue which seems to occur at line `byte[] btDataFile = new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(base64);`

Comment: Can you post the entire stack trace?

Comment: As suggest by @Ant Kutschera, using org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64 works, I now have an "Access is denied" error thrown now when the file is being created, not when decoding the base64

Answer (score 2):

You need to use an escape character since the backslash is reserved by java. Try a double backslash like this

```
File of = new File("driverLetter:\\folder_path\\filename.png");
```

Answer (score 1):

It also suggested to use

```
File.separator
```

Comment: @MByD Are you,guys, proposing `"driverLetter:" + File.separator + "folder_path" + File.separator +"filename.png"`? Good Luck!